# geom_density total AUC 1, instead of 1 for each group

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to make a density plot using `ggplot`, of a variable (x) showing the two levels of a grouping variable (cat). I can do this with `geom_density`

```
cat <- factor(sample(LETTERS[1:2], 2000, replace = T, prob = c(.9, .1)))
distrA <- rnorm(2000, 5, 2)
distrB <- rexp(2000, 1/4)
x <- ifelse(cat == 'A', distrA, distrB)

ggplot(data.frame(x, cat), aes(x)) +
  geom_density(aes(fill = cat), alpha = .4, adjust = 2)
```

[image]

The problem is that it scales the area under the curve for both groups to 1. However I want the total AUC (over the two groups) to be 1, but still showing two curves for the two groups. In the above example the AUC of group A should be around .9 and that of group B about .1. Can anyone tell me if this is possible, and if so, how to do it.

Comment: I thought this ggplot(data.frame(x, cat), aes(x, y=..count../2000))  + geom_density(aes(fill = cat), alpha = .4, adjust = 2) . Maybe something along these lines?